# MongoDB $group performance

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have to collections: Account and MyCollection.
MyCollection has a One To Many relationship with account.
This relation is set by storing the id of the linked Account into MyCollection.

I need to filter MyCollection by an attribute of Account, and I need to extract only one MyCollection object per Account.

Here is the request I am making and an overview of my data structure:

```
// The document structure
Account: {
  types: ["type_A"],  // An indexed array
}

MyCollection: {
  accountId: "accountId",  // Id of the linked account, indexed
  date: new ISODate(),  // an indexed date
  // Other data that we need
}


// The actual request
db.MyCollection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {someData: "foo"},
  },
  {
    $sort: {date: -1},
  },
  // Inject foreign account
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Account",
      localField: "accountId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "account",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$account",
  },
  // match account type
  {
    $match: {
      "account.type": {$in: ["type_A", "type_B"]},
    },
  },
  // And extract latest document
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$accountId",
      myCollection: {$first: "$$ROOT"},
    },
  },
]);
```

This request gives me the correct results, but takes several minutes to process...

How can I speed up all this ? I have an index on Account.type, but it is not used here.
My tests  showed that it is the $group operation that is the most time consuming (the request takes half a second without it).

Comment: What will be the change in execution time if you add `{ "$sort" : { "accountId" : 1 } }` just before `$group` ?

Comment: Yeah, it greatly reduce the time. From around 3 minutes to 3 seconds. But this sort exceed the memory limit and I need to allow disk use (which I would like to avoid).

Comment: What if you add an index on accountId: `{accountId:1}` and then remove the `sort` stage. What are you observing then?

Comment: I have an index on this one. I will edit my question to reflect this.